# Multiple promise requests chained together in Javascript

Tags: javascript, request, promise

I am attempting to chain together multiple asynchronous requests in JS. Basically, I want to retrieve the artist info from the LastFM API, then using that info lookup their top tracks.

So far, I can successfully get the artists info, have it return, and it prints out the info in the next step. However, once I try to do my second request for the top tracks, the body is never printed and it immediately moves on to the next step.

I have tried many many different combinations of this code with different kinds of requests and such but I haven't gotten any luck. I just want to successfully do request 1 if successful then follow it up by others in a proper order.

```
        var artistInfo = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/db/artistInfo/' + artistName
        };


        var topTracks = { method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/db/topTracks/' + artistName
        };

        /* Dependencies */
        var Promise = require('bluebird');
        var reqP = Promise.promisifyAll(require('request-promise'));

        reqP(artistInfo)
            .then(function(info) {

                console.log("got here 1");
                return info;
            })
            .then(function(artist) {

                console.log(artist);

                reqP(topTracks)
                    .then(function(body) {

                        console.log(body);

                        console.log("got here 2");
                        return body;
                });

                return 'test';
            })
            .then(function(content) {

                console.log(content);

                return 'test2';
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                throw err;
            });
```

Comment: Why are you sequencing these two requests?  One does not appear to depend upon the other.  You could launch them in parallel and use `Promise.all()` to see when they are both done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sequence these two requests and have the outer `.then()` wait for both, you need to return the internal promise (the one inside the `.then()` handler) in order to chain them.  If you don't return them, then then nothing is chained to the parent promise and therefore the parent promise doesn't wait for the child promise.  See the line where I added `return` to `return reqP(topTracks)`:

```
   var artistInfo = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/db/artistInfo/' + artistName
    };


    var topTracks = { method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/db/topTracks/' + artistName
    };

    /* Dependencies */
    var Promise = require('bluebird');
    var reqP = Promise.promisifyAll(require('request-promise'));

    reqP(artistInfo)
        .then(function(info) {

            console.log("got here 1");
            return info;
        })
        .then(function(artist) {

            console.log(artist);

            // *** add return here ***
            return reqP(topTracks)
                .then(function(body) {

                    console.log(body);

                    console.log("got here 2");
                    return body;
            });
        })
        .then(function(content) {

            console.log(content);

            return 'test2';
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            throw err;
        });
```

---

FYI, it doesn't look like your two requests depend upon one another so you could also do them in parallel:

```
    var artistInfo = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/db/artistInfo/' + artistName
    };

    var topTracks = { method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/db/topTracks/' + artistName
    };

    /* Dependencies */
    var Promise = require('bluebird');
    var reqP = Promise.promisifyAll(require('request-promise'));

    Promise.all([reqP(artistInfo), reqP(topTracks)]).then(function(results){
        // results[0] is artist
        // results[1] is tracks
    }, function(err){
        // error here
    });
```

Comment: I have tried this with a return there. Just did it again and like before its not even logging "got here 2". It tells me that it hits the request since I have in my request a log saying  "Top Track Success" but it never logs the body and I really can't figure out why (I also got rid of the return test bit).

Comment: @mw - Then you have some errors or logic problem somewhere.  Returning the promise is how you chain it.  That's how it's done.  If you're seeing the `console.log(artist)`, but not seeing `console.log("got here 2")`, then `reqP(toptracks)` must be rejecting.

Comment: No I am seeing from within 'http://localhost:3000/users/db/topTracks/' a log where it prints out a success message. However it never does `console.log(body)` or anything below it.

Comment: @mw - Not much I can tell you about that.  If your `.then()` handler isn't getting called, then add an error handler (the 2nd argument to `.then()`) and log that.  One or the other has to be getting called or `reqP()` is broken.

Comment: @mw - I added another option since your two requests don't look like they even need to be sequenced.

Comment: Thank you! The second code snippet worked perfectly this was exactly what I was looking for. A quick and simple way.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't know why you are promisifying a promise-based library. There are a couple of ways to do this, but I am going to give you what I think is the cleanest way, but it requires bluebird (which you are using in your example anyway, so shouldn't be a problem)

It doesn't look like your second request depends on your first, you can use `Promise.props()`

```js
/* Dependencies */
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = require('request-promise');

var artistInfo = request({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/db/artistInfo/' + artistName
});


var topTracks = request({ 
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/db/topTracks/' + artistName
});



Promise.props({
  artistInfo: artistInfo,
  topTracks: topTracks
}).then(function(result) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result.artistInfo,null,2));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result.topTracks,null,2));
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});
```

So what is going on here? `Promise.props` allows you to pass an object whose properties are promises. These promises will then execute in parallel and the promise won't be resolved until both are resolved (or it will drop to catch if either fail).

As for chaining promises, you need to make sure to return a promise. This is what allows you to avoid the ugly nesting

```js
/* Dependencies */
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = require('request-promise');

request({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/db/artistInfo/' + artistName
})
.then(function(artistInfo) {
  console.log(artistInfo);
  
  return request({ 
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/db/topTracks/' + artistName
  });
})
.then(function(topTracks) {
  console.log(topTracks);
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});
```